# SABR PDE spot/forward upper boundary condition implementation

Tags: options, option-pricing, programming, numerical-methods, finite-difference-method

When running my Finite Difference code, I observe something odd.

Although implementing a classical (non-reverting) SABR model, I initialized the variables such that it should be equal to Black-Scholes.

Boundary conditions for

- Lower bound on price
- Lower bound on volatility
- Upper bound on volatility

are Dirichlet-style (just set equal to a value).

For the upper bound on forward price ($F$), I want to set the Neumann condition of $\Gamma=0$, since I believe this is true for all (put and call) options for large underlying price. This condition yields:

$\dfrac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial F})^2+\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial^2 x}{\partial F^2}=\Gamma=0$

Note that the extra terms with $x$ and $F$ are due to my variable transformation from $F$ to $x$.

**Edit June 19:** @Yian_Pap I agree, lets forget about smoothing condition and focus on getting Neumann condition working. Let me be specific regarding my steps applying your approach :) This is how I would currently implement it, but once again I'm not very familiar with FD (this is my first use case):

- First of all, it is not immediately clear to me what PDE to start with (pricing equation? or just the $\Gamma=0$ equation?). If we start from $\Gamma=0$, why would we bother about cross derivative term being 0 or not?
- If I start with $\Gamma=0$, no transformations in F, then

$\dfrac{\partial^2 V}{\partial F^2} = 0$

discretize using 2nd order central FD approx,

$\dfrac{1}{\Delta F^2} (V_{N-1,j} - 2V_{N,j} + V_{N+1,j}) = 0$,

$V_{N,j}=\dfrac{1}{2}(V_{N-1,j}+V_{N+1,j})$ (1),

which contains the outer grid point $V_{N+1,j}$, which I assume you mean in your answer?

Then, as I understand your comment regarding that the first derivative at $F \to \infty$ is known and constant, you mean that the delta is 1 (0) for a call (put)?

$\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial F} = \Delta = 1$,

$V_{N,j} = \Delta F + V_{N-1,j}$,

use this to substitute $V_{N+1,j}$ in (1),

$V_{N,j} = \Delta F + V_{N-1,j}$,

with $\Delta F$ step size in F. Then I can incorporate this in the coefficient matrix as follows. (Side question: why not use $\Delta=1$ condition directly?)

Say I have implicit scheme $V_{i,j,k} = z_1V_{i-1,j,k+1} + z_2V_{i,j,k+1} + z_3V_{i+1,j,k+1}$. Then for some i (i.e. at some places in matrix) $V_{i+1,j}$ is a bound, hence matrix entry is set $0$. Incorporate bound by adding $z_3$ to $z_2$ at every place in matrix where $i=N-1$. Additionally add $z_3\Delta F$. Mathematically,

$V_{N-1,j,k} = z_1V_{N-2,j,k+1} + (z_2+z_3)V_{N-1,j,k+1} + z_3\Delta F$.

**Would this be a correct understanding of how the upper bound F Neumann condition should be implemented?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever your discretized PDE references $V_{N,j,k+1}$, you will use your expression for $V_{N,j,k+1}$ in terms of $V_{N−1,j,k+1}$ and $V_{N−2,j,k+1}$ to eliminate $V_{N,j,k+1}$ from the discretized equation. This means that the algebraic system you will solve will not involve any $V_{N,j,k+1}$  values directly (so no $C_{k+1}$ contribution from the F-discretization). Rather you will be augmenting the system coefficients of the $V_{N−1,j,k+1}$ and $V_{N−2,j,k+1}$ points accordingly.

**Edit Jun 18**. OK, let's start again and assume you are using the pricing PDE in the forward F (no transformations). If you use a smoothing condition you'd need to use one-sided finite difference approximations so that you can close your algebraic system at the last line $F=F_{max}$. That said, the reason why you opted for this kind of (smoothing) condition is because when you tried with Neumann, you didn't get correct results. But this was most probably because you made an error somewhere. I would try again as follows for the last line of points of your grid: the first derivative in F (let's call it $D_{F\to\infty}$) you already know (you know its value from the Neumann condition), so this doesn't need to be discretized on the boundary, you just use its known value. The cross derivative also becomes zero there since the first derivative in the F-direction is constant (even in the general case where $\nu$ is not zero). The only derivative in the F-direction that you'll need to discretize is the second derivative and that will reference a point outside your grid (with the standard 2nd order central FD approximation). This "fictitious" point in your discretized equations you will replace by its extrapolated value as $V_{N+1,j,k+1} = V_{N,j,k+1} + D_{F\to\infty} d_F $. This will again close your system and you're good to go. Try and let me know if something is still not clear.

Comment: I would also change the question title to something more specific like "SABR PDE far-right boundary condition implementation", although your question is really generic finite differences.

Comment: @Yian_Pap Thank you for your answer. While implementing the approach you mention, I dont understand the following. Solving and rewriting the PDE, I obtain the expression for a point on the spot price bound $V_{N,j,k} = z_1 V_{N-1,j,k+1} + z_2 V_{N-2,j,k+1} + z_3 V_{N,j,k+1}$. I can then rewrite to $V_{N,j,k+1} = z_1^{*} V_{N-1,j,k+1} + z_2^{*} V_{N-2,j,k+1} + z_3^{*} V_{N,j,k}$ ("formula X"). In the point $V_{N-1,j,k+1}$ I can then substitute this expression to rule out $V_{N,j,k+1}$. However, I do get back a term $V_{N,j,k}$ (see formula "X"). Is this OK? How to know its value for $k\neq0$?

Comment: Why do you have $V_{N,j,k}$ in the expression? The Neumann condition doesn't involve a time derivative, so I'm not sure how you came up with an expression involving points at both k and k+1. It should involve only points at k+1.

Comment: @Yian_Pap I just started with the (reduced, since $\nu=0$, $\beta=1$) PDE: $\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial \tau} = \dfrac{\sigma_F^2}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 V}{\partial F^2}$ and substituted FD approximations for the derivatives. Then rewrite according to my previous comment. Could you explain what would be the correct way to come up with an expression for $V_{N,j,k+1}$ not involving time derivative?

Comment: @Yian_Pap I do understand how the $\Gamma=0$ Neumann condition does not involve a time derivative. However, I forgot to mention but updated my post just now, today I have been looking to enforce the PDE itself as Neumann condition due to strange results with the earlier mentioned boundary condition.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer. Also, you are saying that the PDE at the far right F-boundary becomes (the smoothing condition) $\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial \tau} = \dfrac{\sigma_F^2}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 V}{\partial F^2}$ when $\nu=0$ and $\beta=1$, but unless I'm missing something it should be $\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial \tau} = \dfrac{\sigma_F^2}{2}F^{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 V}{\partial F^2} -rV$

Comment: Thanks again for your time. I updated my question regarding the Neumann condition approach, lets forget Smoothing for now as you rightfully point out. (Regarding your last comment, I set r=0 to rule out any mistake with discounting)

Comment: If you don't mind me saying, there are multiple places in your updated question that show confusion. And perhaps rightfully so, a 2D PDE is not what a finite difference beginner would choose for learning! So I am not sure how to proceed from here honestly. For example, when you say what PDE to start with, what do you mean? You discretize the pricing PDE in order to find the value of the option (obviously) and on the boundary line you do sth special, in this case you set the 1st derivative to 1 or 0 yes. I am not sure what $\Gamma=0$ is tbh. Also a 2nd order FD scheme is 2nd order accurate, etc

Comment: With what PDE to start at, I meant that if I start at $\dfrac{\partial^2 V}{\partial F^2}=0$ and just replace this with its FD approx I obtain expression shown in edited question. But I'm not sure this is the way to go. I get a feeling that maybe I should substitute the $=0$ condition **into** the PDE. But $\dfrac{\partial^2 V}{\partial F^2}=0$, $\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial F}=1$ and cross deriv 0 as well, leaves me with a PDE that only has derivatives in vol dimension...? With $\Gamma=0$ I mean that options greek Gamma is zero at forward upper bound.

Comment: I am still not sure what do you mean by start at. Are you talking about how to find the boundary condition or how to solve the PDE at the boundary? In the first case you don't "start from" nowhere (unless it's the smoothing condition you want to derive/apply), you just accept that at the boundary your chosen condition will apply. In the second case you obviously start from the PDE itself and substitute your bc there, otherwise keeping the original PDE as is.

Comment: Setting the 2nd derivative to zero at the boundary is another kind of bc as Antoine mentioned here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/40375/upper-bound-option-price-in-volatility-dimension. But you cannot use both this and the Neumann condition, you have to choose one of them.

Comment: Okay, then in my implementation I was not using Neumann condition, rather just setting 2nd deriv to zero. So if I want to use Neumann instead, then my question is about the resulting equation when substituting the 2nd deriv equals $0$ in the PDE. As explained in my comment above, it looks to me I end up with this: $\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial \tau}=\dfrac{\sigma_{\alpha}^2 \partial^2V}{2 \partial \alpha^2} + \mu_F\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial F}\text{(=0 or 1)} + \mu_{\alpha}\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial \alpha} - rV$..? I cant thank you enough for your time and understanding!

Comment: As I said, you cannot use the Neumann condition AND set the 2nd deriv to zero. So your equation above needs the 2nd deriv in F as well. And then you handle that as I described above in my answer. You're welcome by the way:)

Comment: Two more small questions: (1) Why is it allowed when setting Neumann $\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial F}=1$ (or $0$) to infer that the cross deriv is zero, but not - with the same reasoning - that the 2nd deriv in F is zero? (2) A neumann condition cannot be a second order deriv (setting 2nd order deriv in F to zero)?

Comment: (1) Fair question I guess:) Well you can, but then, intuitively, there'd be nothing left in the equation at the boundary to force the kind of solution behavior we want there since the discretized eq wouldn't involve more than 1 point in the F-direction. We'd need at least two. (2) A Neumann condition is by definition setting the 1st derivative to a constant value, just a matter of definition.